# Setting UICollectionViewLayout class in Storyboard

Tags: uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

I want to use this excellent `UICollectionView` layout: https://github.com/bryceredd/RFQuiltLayout

As expected, it wants me to set my Collection View's layout class to it. This can't be done, because Xcode does not accept `RFQuiltLayout` in the class field (beeps, and clears the field if I select anything else).

I tried this with a new, empty project too.

What did I wrong?

(Tried in both Xcode 4.2.1/iOS 6 and Xcode 5/iOS 7, OS X Mavericks.)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You are probably trying to set it in the Class field of the Identity Inspector, which is for the UICollectionView's class or subclass.

Instead, open the CollectionView's Attributes Inspector, select `Layout > Custom` and below `Class > RFQuiltLayout`:

[image]